# NodeJS URL parsing results wrong

Tags: node.js, parsing, url

Here is the code:

```
var url = require('url');
console.log(url.parse('localhost:3000'));
```

Results in output like follows:

```
{ protocol: 'localhost:',
  host: '3000',
  hostname: '3000',
  href: 'localhost:3000' }
```

Very weird. I guess this is because of no existence of 'http' at the beginning. for such case, I was expecting something like:

```
{ port: '3000',
  host: 'localhost',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  href: 'localhost:3000' }
```

Any third party good libraries or suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: So, when you say "wrong" you really mean just not what you want, right? Did you at least search npm before asking here? https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=url

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking what you passed in is not a valid URL. According to RFC 3986, scheme is not optional:

> ```
> URI = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
>
>   hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
>               / path-absolute
>               / path-rootless
>               / path-empty
> ```

Having said that, of course Node.js could have warned about the invalid URL in this case.

In my opinion, in such a trivial case, instead of searching for an additional library, might be better just write couple lines of code to fix the URL first, before passing it into the parser.

**Furthermore**, in this particular case, solely based on the above definition, the parser has every reason to understand localhost as the scheme, instead of the host.